# Using Xbox 360 controller with Mac OS X (specifically turning it off)

Tags: macos, drivers, power-management, xbox360, game-controller

So I've been using [this driver](http://www.tattiebogle.net/index.php/ProjectRoot/Xbox360Controller/OsxDriver) for a few months with the [Xbox 360 Wireless Controller For Windows](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000KA5T6A) with my Mac Mini. Here's an article about the driver on [Gizmodo](http://gizmodo.com/gadgets/home-entertainment/mac-os-x-driver-for-xbox-360-controller-175162.php). The driver works really well for actually using the controller, but there doesn't seem to be a way to power off the controller without pulling the batteries. Does anyone know of a replacement driver that includes power-off capabilities, or know of some other undocumented way to turn the controller off?

Note: I've been having problems getting to the site, but it could be our corporate filtering.

Comment: I can still download the driver and get to the site, can you please explain the site does not exists?

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's our web content filtering at work, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take off the battery pack and put it back on (seriously). However, this is more difficult if you use AA batteries rather than the play and charge pack.

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant. Unfortunately this seems like a workaround.